# Inverse of a matrix in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find the inverse of a 3*3 matrix using SOLVE in R.

```
>a=c(1:3)  
>b=c(4:5)  
>c=c(7:9)  

>n=cbind(a,b,c)  

[1,] 1 4 7  
[2,] 2 5 8  
[3,] 3 6 9  

>det(n)  
0  

>solve(n)  
 Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[3,3] = 0
```

I dont understand , the matrix's determinent is zero and also it is numeric matrix. it still gives singular matrix error.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: square matrix that is not invertible is called singular or degenerate. A square matrix is singular if and only if its determinant is 0.  (From wiki)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about mathematics, and not related to programming.

Comment: The matrix `n` defined in the question by R code is not singular but the matrix that was displayed is not the same as `n` and it is singular.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. it should have been 4:6. I was confused with the definition of a singular matrix. Thank you very much for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix with determinant 0 is called singular and is not invertible. It means that one or more of the rows of your matrix can be made up by linear combinations of the other rows. There is no unique solution to any problem Ax=b, where A is your matrix and b is a solution vector.

Comment: eg `2*n[,'b'] - n[,'a'] - n[,'c']`
`

Comment: Not necessarily only the rows. A matrix is also singular if at least one of the columns is a linear combination of the other columns. The best way to identify a singular matrix is if the determinant is zero.